# Change number of files recentf in emacs stores using ido completion method

Tags: emacs, elisp, recent-file-list

I'm using the ido method listed on this page:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RecentFiles. I want to be able to select the number of recent files it stores. It seems to not store very many. Is there a setting for this or an easy way to do so. Function listed below for reference. Cheers

```
    (defun recentf-interactive-complete ()
  "find a file in the recently open file using ido for completion"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((all-files recentf-list)
     (file-assoc-list (mapcar (lambda (x) (cons (file-name-nondirectory x) x)) all-files))
     (filename-list (remove-duplicates (mapcar 'car file-assoc-list) :test 'string=))
     (ido-make-buffer-list-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq ido-temp-list filename-list)))
     (filename (ido-read-buffer "Find Recent File: "))
     (result-list (delq nil (mapcar (lambda (x) (if (string= (car x) filename) (cdr x))) file-assoc-list)))
     (result-length (length result-list)))
    (find-file 
     (cond 
      ((= result-length 0) filename)
      ((= result-length 1) (car result-list))
      ( t
    (let ( (ido-make-buffer-list-hook
        (lambda ()
          (setq ido-temp-list result-list))))
      (ido-read-buffer (format "%d matches:" result-length))))
      ))))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you need set `recentf-max-saved-items` to a specified value, for example:

```
(setq recentf-max-saved-items 30) ; or what ever you want
```

Comment: This seems to have changed from `recentf-max-menu-items` in old versions.

Comment: No, `recentf-max-menu-items` determines how many items are _shown_, not how many are saved. You could, for example, save the 500 most recent items, and only display the top 30. (You could then use ido or something when you want to take advantage of the deeper history)